# Scheduled stored procedure on all databases in my server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-agent, jobs

On SQL Server 2012 (not express edition) I'd like to schedule the execution of a stored procedure every hour.

On the same server I have lot of databases with the same structure, and I'm constantly adding new db.

How can I schedule the execution of the same stored procedure on all the databases (if this exists in the database)?

Answer (score 10):

Use the [better version of the undocumented sp_MSForEachDB](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior) to iterate through the databases in a SQL Server Agent job.

Or simply use a WHILE loop yourself on sys.database entries if you have a naming pattern.